# Unable to deploy my apk on google play store

Tags: android

our previous apk has been removed from google play store due to new policy because of we are giving permission for READ, SEND and WRITE SMS. Now we have removed all these permission and trying to deploy this modified apk on play store. When we upload it on play store, google ask some permission like Default SMS handler, Phone handler etc. but out app didn't have such permissions. Google restrict us to select at least one permission and when we continue with one of these permission(we are selecting Default SMS handler), every time google is rejecting our apk and removing our apk from play store.

Can any one guide us to get out this problem?

I have searched over google but unable to find how to set permission for Default SMS handler in android manifest.xml?

Comment: Follow  [steps](https://gist.github.com/manishpatelgt/224a330a5d4c7eaf783ca3ff5d522274)

Comment: Use this https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/

Comment: Hi M D, There is nothing like Compliance status on app release form.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permissions which deal with **Reading SMS, OR Call Logs** it will come under the use of [high risk or sensitive permission](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/). Please read that for detail info.

Google Play may provide a temporary exception to apps that aren't Default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handlers when:

1. Use of the permission provides core app functionality to users.
2. There is currently no alternative method to provide the core functionality.

You must fill the [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfbmF-9G249UDLJZpEvJpjgwP8rjvvLyWyNYnFPrsqYjMNckg/closedform) and google will approve it.
If you think that this permissions are necessary for your app and not just useless, you can follow the steps mentioned in the [official document here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Comment: Hi Sam, we don't want to use SMS or Call Logs. Are you asking about Permissions Declaration Form? If yes, then which permission to choose?